# how to load varchar(max) value into mysql server using ssis package

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have one question in ssis
how to load sql server  `VARCHAR(MAX)` data type column related data into mysql server table using ssis package

source : product table ( ms sql server )

```
pid (int)  | productDescrption (varchar(max))
```

Destination : product  table (mysql server )

```
Pid ( int)   | productDescription ( dt_ntext)
```

1. step1: drag and drop oledb source and configure the SQL Server table product
2. step2: change data conversion for `productdescription` `varchar(max)` to `dt_next`
3. step3: configure the destination odbc destination for MySQL product table (here odbc 32 bit driver is installed) and i I ran the package that tim i got error like below:

> [ODBC Destination [2]] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HYC00'. Native Error Code: 0. [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.24-log]Parameter arrays with data at execution are not supported
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ODBC Destination" (2) failed with error code 0x80004005 while processing input "ODBC Destination Input" (13). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Can you please tell me how to achieve this task in ssis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to transfer SQL Server varchar(max) to MySQL text using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875389/unable-to-transfer-sql-server-varcharmax-to-mysql-text-using-ssis)

Comment: I'm working on a better solution but change the destination to Row by Row and it should work.